# Conditional format a cell based on max value of another row

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have two columns in my spreadsheet. I need to highlight the cell in the first column wherever the max cell is in the second column.

```
Column 1     Column 2
Dog           12
Cat           17
Bird          11
```

So for example I would want just the cat cell to be highlighted.

Comment: `=$B1=MAX($B:$B)` and apply to column A.

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula `=$B=MAX($B:$B)` where B is the column you're looking for the max value in.

Example from Google Sheets:

> [image]